# Report server scheduled job location

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-agent, jobs

I inherited a SQL Server environment. In (database engine) SQL Server Agent are two jobs defined that apparently belong to the report server.

First and only step in the first job:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='CacheInvalidateSchedule', @EventData='c5b50dad-33bb-40b8-a696-59b1a555e8e4'
```

First and only step in the second job:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='RefreshCache', @EventData='f1ae0c17-b150-4861-8d9a-8552036123a3'
```

[image]

Any ideas how these two jobs were originally created and what they do? When I check the report server, there are no schedules defined:

[image]

The connected report server is empty:

[image]

Comment: The statements are the first and only step in the respective job. There are no other steps. I have edited my question accordingly. Unfortunately, I cannot check what the stored procedure (AddEvent) does because the connected report server does not contain any database nor does it contain a programmability folder (I assume everything has been developed in visual studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I ran

```
Use ReportServer  
select * from ExecutionLog3 order by TimeStart DESC
```

This gave me a list of events that I matched with the scheduled times of the jobs:

[image]

So I went to the portal and checked the dataset. Turns out caching was enabled:

[image]